# ¿Como puedo transformar una imagen a byte via URL en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

he estado intentando converir una imagen a bytes via URL esto con el fin de insertarla en un campo BLOB de SQLite, por el momento no he logrado realizar agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

```
String add = "https://static.teamviewer.com/resources/2018/05/android.png";
  URL url = null;
  Bitmap image = null;
   try {
         url = new URL(add);
         image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres a convertir el Bitmap a Byte array, esto lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
...
...
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

//Aquí se obtiene el byte array en base al bitmap.
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
image.recycle();
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, he implementado tu consejo, pero aun no inserta de forma correcta la imagen en el campo BLOB de SQLite.